# Automation frameworks for mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, unit-testing, mobile, automated-tests

I am trying to use automation frameworks similar to Selenium to test native apps (both android and IOS apps). Does anyone have a list of frameworks that is suitable for the tasks. Java based frameworks are preferred but others are welcome too. I want to go over the merits of each framework and make a final determination

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of options to test mobile applications, not all are cross platform though. You say this is important to you so I would either say MonkeyTalk (http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk) calabash (http://blog.lesspainful.com/) or the new Calabash Driver projects (A form of calabash made to look and feel more like selenium from the ebay guys just recently announced) https://github.com/calabash-driver/calabash-driver and https://github.com/freynaud/ios-driver.

Answer (score 2):

[Appium](http://appium.io/) is a Selenium-compatible mobile automation tool which lets you write tests in Java and other languages using the Selenium client libraries.

Comment: Great, I have been looking for such a open source for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

My team has been using Frank for the past 14 months and it's been working out really well for us. It describes itself as: "Selenium for native iOS apps". It's a fairly active project, and has a small community that's very helpful.

You can get started here: [Testing With Frank](http://testingwithfrank.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS: Unlike the ruby based [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank), [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) is a 100% obj-c solution, which makes for easier integration with your iOS code.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229460/kif-how-to-auto-run-stress-test-an-ios-app-to-find-the-cause-of-a-rare-ui-bug/17289283#17289283) for an example of how I used [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) for my iOS project and the reason why I chose it over Frank.